# Swiftchars - bars chart overlap after specific number of points

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftcharts

- How can I specify min space between bars in bar chart using SwiftChars library ?

  - Here is my code sample for using SwiftCharts to display bars chart:

  ```
  // xAxis

   let labelSettings = ChartLabelSettings(font: .systemFont(ofSize: 13.0), fontColor: .aiduBlue)

   var xValues = [ChartAxisValue]()
   xValues.append(ChartAxisValueString(order: -1))
   for (index, point) in barsDataSource.enumerated() {
       let dateString = DateFormatter.shortDayOfWeekDayOnTwoLinesFormatter.string(from: point.departureDate)
       xValues.append(ChartAxisValueString(dateString, order: index, labelSettings: labelSettings))
   }
   xValues.append(ChartAxisValueString(order: xValues.count - 1))
   let xModel = ChartAxisModel(axisValues: xValues,
                               lineColor: .aiduSkyBlue,
                               axisTitleLabel: ChartAxisLabel(text: "", settings: labelSettings))

   // yAxis

   let yAxisMinSpaceBetweenPoints: CGFloat = 10.0
   let yAxisTopBottomMargin = (((barsMaxPrice - barsMinPrice) / Double(barsDataSource.count)) + Double(yAxisMinSpaceBetweenPoints)) + 10
   let yAxisGenerator = ChartAxisValuesGeneratorNice(minValue: barsMinPrice - yAxisTopBottomMargin,
                                                     maxValue: barsMaxPrice + yAxisTopBottomMargin,
                                                     preferredDividers: 1,
                                                     minSpace: yAxisMinSpaceBetweenPoints,
                                                     maxTextSize: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude,
                                                     multiplierUpdateMode: .nice)
   let yLabelsGenerator = ChartAxisLabelsGeneratorFunc {scalar in
       return ChartAxisLabel(text: "", settings: ChartLabelSettings())
   }
   let yModel = ChartAxisModel(lineColor: UIColor.white.withAlphaComponent(0),
                               firstModelValue: barsMinPrice,
                               lastModelValue: barsMaxPrice,
                               axisTitleLabels: [],
                               axisValuesGenerator: yAxisGenerator,
                               labelsGenerator: yLabelsGenerator)

   // Char Bars layer

   let frame = chartFrame(containerView.bounds)
   let coordsSpace = ChartCoordsSpaceLeftBottomSingleAxis(chartSettings: chartSettings,
                                                          chartFrame: frame,
                                                          xModel: xModel,
                                                          yModel: yModel)
   let (xAxisLayer, yAxisLayer, innerFrame) = (coordsSpace.xAxisLayer, coordsSpace.yAxisLayer, coordsSpace.chartInnerFrame)

   let barsModels: [ChartBarModel] = barsDataSource.enumerated().flatMap { index, item in
       [
           ChartBarModel(constant: ChartAxisValueInt(index),
                         axisValue1: ChartAxisValueDouble(0),
                         axisValue2: ChartAxisValueDouble(item.price),
                         bgColor: barColor(price: item.price, minPrice: barsMinPrice))
       ]
   }

   let chartBarSettings = ChartBarViewSettings(animDuration: 0,
                                               animDelay: 0,
                                               cornerRadius: 0,
                                               roundedCorners: .allCorners,
                                               selectionViewUpdater: nil,
                                               delayInit: false)

   let chartBarsLayer =  ChartBarsLayer(xAxis: xAxisLayer.axis,
                                        yAxis: yAxisLayer.axis,
                                        bars: barsModels,
                                        horizontal: false,
                                        barWidth: 40,
                                        settings: chartBarSettings,
                                        mode: .translate,
                                        tapHandler: { [weak self] (tappedBar) in
                                           self?.chartBarTapHandler(tappedBar: tappedBar)
       }, viewGenerator: { [weak self] (p1, p2, barWidth, color, settings, model, index) -> ChartPointViewBar in
           var barBGColor = color
           if let s = self, let lastTappedBarModel = s.lastTappedBarModel {
               let currentBarModel = s.dataSource[index]
               barBGColor = currentBarModel.departureDate == lastTappedBarModel.departureDate && currentBarModel.duration == lastTappedBarModel.duration ? s.barSelectionBgColor : color
           }
           let view = ChartPointViewBar(p1: p1, p2: p2, width: barWidth, bgColor: barBGColor, settings: settings)
           return view
   })

   // Price labels layer

   let labelToBarSpace: Double = 20
   let labelChartPoints = barsModels.map { bar in
       ChartPoint(x: bar.constant, y: bar.axisValue2.copy(bar.axisValue2.scalar + labelToBarSpace))
   }

   let priceLabelsLayer = ChartPointsViewsLayer(xAxis: xAxisLayer.axis,
                                                yAxis: yAxisLayer.axis,
                                                chartPoints: labelChartPoints,
                                                viewGenerator: {(chartPointModel, layer, chart) -> UIView? in
                                                   let label = HandlingLabel()
                                                   label.text = PriceFormatter.string(fromPrice: Float(chartPointModel.chartPoint.y.scalar - labelToBarSpace))
                                                   label.font = .boldSystemFont(ofSize: 10.0)
                                                   label.textColor = UIColor.aiduBlue
                                                   label.sizeToFit()
                                                   let pos = chartPointModel.chartPoint.y.scalar > 0
                                                   label.center = CGPoint(x: chartPointModel.screenLoc.x, y: pos ? innerFrame.origin.y : innerFrame.origin.y + innerFrame.size.height)
                                                   label.alpha = 0
                                                   label.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
                                                   label.movedToSuperViewHandler = {[weak label] in
                                                       label?.alpha = 1
                                                       label?.center.y = chartPointModel.screenLoc.y
                                                   }
                                                   return label
   }, displayDelay: 0, mode: .translate)

   return Chart(
       frame: frame,
       innerFrame: innerFrame,
       settings: chartSettings,
       layers: [
           xAxisLayer,
           yAxisLayer,
           chartBarsLayer,
           priceLabelsLayer
       ]
   )

  private var chartSettings: ChartSettings {
       var chartSettings = ChartSettings()
       chartSettings.leading = 2
       chartSettings.top = 2
       chartSettings.trailing = 2
       chartSettings.bottom = 2
       chartSettings.axisStrokeWidth = 0.4
       chartSettings.spacingBetweenAxesX = 2
       chartSettings.spacingBetweenAxesY = 2
       chartSettings.labelsSpacing = 10
       chartSettings.labelsToAxisSpacingY = 0
       chartSettings.spacingBetweenAxesY = 0
       chartSettings.axisTitleLabelsToLabelsSpacing = 0
       chartSettings.zoomPan.panEnabled = true
       chartSettings.zoomPan.zoomEnabled = false
       chartSettings.zoomPan.maxZoomX = 3
       chartSettings.zoomPan.minZoomX = 3
       chartSettings.zoomPan.minZoomY = 1
       chartSettings.zoomPan.maxZoomY = 1
       return chartSettings
   }
  ```

  - When data source contains around (10 for ex) points, chart working without overlapping, but without fixed space between bars if you changed (increase/decrease) data source:
    [image: without overlapping]
  - When data source contains around (35 for ex) points, bars overlapped:
    [image: overlapping]

SwiftCharts version 0.6.5
Swift version 5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found solution:

I had to set the minZoomX and maxZoomX (in chart settings) with fixed value which the number of pages for the chart (or number of scrollable area than the original width).
why x ? because I want chart to scroll horizontally.

here is code:

```
        let barWidth: CGFloat = 30.0
        let spaceBetweenBars: CGFloat = 80.0

        let zoomXValue = CGFloat(barsDataSource.count) / (UIScreen.main.bounds.width / (barWidth + spaceBetweenBars))
        chartSettings.zoomPan.minZoomX = zoomXValue
        chartSettings.zoomPan.maxZoomX = zoomXValue
```